# Android Google Maps - Get current tilt, bearing and zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am building an android app on google maps, which shows the current location of the user, and constantly updates it.

Now, what I want is, if as a user, I zoom out in maps, and change my bearing, I want my camera to keep that zoom, bearing and tilt.

This is what I have used so far -

```
public void setupLocationOnMap(){
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());

            if(firstTimeSetup) {
                cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(-30).tilt(30).build();
                firstTimeSetup = false;
            } else {
                cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLatLng).build();
            }
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }
```

This function gets called on onLocationChanged(Location location) callback. What I want to achieve is, in the 'else' part, if a user has changed his zoom or bearing, I want to maintain that zoom and bearing and tilt in the camera. I do not want to set the camera, each time a location is updated, to a certain predefined value. I want to get the current zoom, bearing and tilt, and set the camera to that, only (lat,lang) needs to be updated.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain current camera position and use those values:https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getCameraPosition()

> **Gets the current position of the camera.** 
>   The CameraPosition returned is a snapshot of the current position, and will not automatically update when the camera moves

So you can do:

```
CameraPosition currentposition=googlemap.getCameraPosition();
currentposition.tilt
currentposition.bearing
currentposition.zoom
```

You now have all the needed values!